# Certificates are not auto populated after the successful association of UWP project with microsoft store

Tags: uwp, certificate

I did the following steps to fetch the certificates in UWP from the Microsoft Store.

Association of UWP Project

1. Right clicked on the UWP project.
2. Clicked on the publish option.
3. Then clicked on the associate app with store and clicked on next button.
4. Logged in with my company account credentials.
5. Then list of our company apps got populated then, I selected our app and clicked on next to associate the app.
6. The association was successful.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Selection of Certificate.

1. After the successful association
2. Right clicked on the UWP project.
3. Selected create App packages option.
4. Then selected the sideloading option and clicked on next.
5. When I clicked the "Select from Store" option there were no certificates populated.

[image]

I with Visual studio 2019 and 2022 but no progress. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Any updates for this thread? does the following answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Certificates are not auto populated after the successful association of UWP project with microsoft store

This behavior is by design. When you associate your app with Store, it will create a `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` file which contains the name of your app and some other information. The association will not create a certificate for you. So there is no certificate that you could choose in the certificate Store.

If you want to create a sideload package, you will still need to create your own **test certificate**.